# ThreeJS TransformControl release control

Tags: typescript, three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm doing this using Typescript and on Autodesk Forge Viewer. I am trying to limit the movement of ThreeJS transform control. I have a defined area where the mesh can be moved (defined by min max X, Y, Z). I also record the change in mesh position using a prev_pos variable.

In the 'change' event listener of the Transform Control, I would check the current mesh position against the min max X, Y, Z.

In here, after the check, if the mesh position is outside the area, I reset the mesh position to the limit. I also set prev_pos to this limit position. However, I also want to release the control from the transform control, so that the transform control would reset its position to the attached mesh position.

currently, the attached mesh resets to the limit, but the control can still be dragged. After that, the position of the control is offset from the mesh, an everytime I hover the mouse over the control, and the mesh moved by itself despite no move button down. I also tried resetting the control position by using transformControl.position.copy(mesh.position) but didn't work. Here is the code for 'change' event:

```
 public onTxChange() {
console.log("TxChange");
if (!this.allowUpdate) {
  return;
}
let position: THREE.Vector3 = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
if (this.m_mesh !== null) {

  position.x = this.m_mesh.position.x;
  position.y = this.m_mesh.position.y;
  position.z = this.m_mesh.position.z;

}
else {
  return;
}
const scaffoldGroupInfo: scaffold_group_info = g_scaffold_docking_panel_cmn.getScaffoldGroupInfo();
const color: string = scaffoldGroupInfo.color;
let deltaX: number = position.x - this.m_prevPos.x;
let deltaY: number = position.y - this.m_prevPos.y;
let deltaZ: number = position.z - this.m_prevPos.z;
console.log("DeltaX");
console.log(deltaX);
if (deltaX > 0) {
  scaffold_cmn.cubeExpantion(g_scaffold_docking_panel_cmn.getsetHomePosition(), "X", false, color, deltaX);
}
else if (deltaX < 0) {
  scaffold_cmn.cubeExpantion(g_scaffold_docking_panel_cmn.getsetHomePosition(), "X", true, color, deltaX * -1);
}
if (deltaY > 0) {
  scaffold_cmn.cubeExpantion(g_scaffold_docking_panel_cmn.getsetHomePosition(), "Y", false, color, deltaY * 1);
}
else if (deltaY < 0) {
  scaffold_cmn.cubeExpantion(g_scaffold_docking_panel_cmn.getsetHomePosition(), "Y", true, color, deltaY * -1);
}
if (deltaZ > 0) {
  scaffold_cmn.cubeExpantion(g_scaffold_docking_panel_cmn.getsetHomePosition(), "Z", true, color, deltaZ);
}
else if (deltaZ < 0) {
  scaffold_cmn.cubeExpantion(g_scaffold_docking_panel_cmn.getsetHomePosition(), "Z", false, color, deltaZ * -1);
}

if (!scaffold_cmn.CubeResizable) {
  scaffold_cmn.ResetAttachedMeshPositionRotation();
  return;
}
this.m_prevPos = position;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve that by simply limiting the position of the object being moved, for example, using this code in the `change` event handler (as suggested in this three.js discourse [thread](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-limit-thetransformcontrol-move-space/11492)):

```js
const min = new THREE.Vector3(-100, -100, -100);
const max = new THREE.Vector3(100, 100, 100);
transformControl.object.position.clamp(min, max);
```

The position of the transform control should update to the object's position next time its `update` method is called, as can be seen here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r71/examples/js/controls/TransformControls.js#L702.

Note that a simialar